# Spring TransactionTemplate setPropagationBehavior

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, transactions

I am wondering what exactly `setPropagationBehavior` of the `TransactionTemplate` does. Who propagats what to whom? I see it is well documented but I don't grasp the basic concept of this `PropagationBehavior`.

The default is `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`, so what does this meen? Does the template report (propagate) failures or vice versa?

Can someone please explain in a basic way what is going on here, I am familiar with database terminology and transaction functionality, ACID and so on.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TransactionManager takes care of transactions in application. PropagationBehavior is a way how to tell your manager how do you want transactions to behave. TransactionTemplate is a helper class to simplifi this for you.

REQUIRED means:

1.If the calling method is already in a transaction it will use the same transaction

2.If the calling method is in a non-transaction scope it will create new transaction

**EDIT:** I came accross [this](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/thread-safe/index.jsp) very good article dealing with web applications spring andm multithreading. I think you should read [it](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/thread-safe/index.jsp).

Comment: okay so if new transaction shall be started for new threads I need not care about this feature? I don't have any code where multiple calls to doInTransaction are made. The execute command blocks until the transaction is finished, doesn't it?

Comment: The excecute method executes the doInTransaction method of its callback, then commits or rollbacks the transaction, and then returns. TransactionTemplate doesn't handle threads that might be started by the callback. These execute outside of the transaction context.

Comment: Demarcation of transaction is the service method. That means boundary of transaction is within this method where the work is done. Transation eather commits or it is rolled back if there is exception. Everything out of this unit of work is out of this transaction context.

Comment: I edited my answer, wher eI added link to a good article aboud multithreading and spring.

Answer (score 2):

The propagation is not about propagating failures. `REQUIRED` means: if there is already a transaction running, do the work (in the template callback) in the current transaction. If there is no transaction running, start a new one, execute the work in the callback, and then commit the transaction (or rollback it if there is a runtime exception).

In all the cases, a runtime exception is always propagated to the caller. It also cause the transaction to rollback, even if it wasn't started by this template.